# How to remove stopwords from a multilingual excel text data

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, text-processing

I'm working on a multilanguage text data where some text cleaning steps are to be done. I'm using spacy library for the removal of stopwords, so for multilanguage spacy has a package called `spacy.load("xx_ent_wiki_sm")` which is giving me error as follows.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error basically means that the spacy module doesnt recognize this function.
Edit: take a look at the spacy documentation [here](https://spacy.io/usage/adding-languages).

Answer (score 0):

After checking out Spacy's [Github](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/lang/xx/__init__.py), it seems like multilanguage models do not support STOP_WORDS. In other words, the module your are trying to import does not exist.